# Visual Studio 2016 Winforms Application Not Reading exe.config file (mostly)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I developed a simple WinForms application, which gets its startup parameters from app.config file.  That file is configured with values suitable for development and testing.

I created a setup project, and after much tweaking it installs the application.  I can run from the installed exe, and it uses the myExe.exe.config file to get its parameters.  I edited the file to changed the parameters, but the old parameters are still being used.  I made sure the application directory, the executable and the config file all have full control for everyone.  Not ideal I know, but to get it working...

Still, the program runs with the old parameters.  UNLESS... I right-click on the executable and select Run As Administrator.  Then, it uses the properly configured parameters.

Any ideas what is causing this behavior and how to fix?  Thanks...

Comment: Are you rerunning the winform application after the config changes?

Comment: Yes I am, that's the problem. The application should read the current config values and act accordingly, but it only does so if I run as administrator.

Comment: By the way, this problem occurs whether I use the

`<appSettings>
  <add key="" value=""/>
</appSettings>`
method, or the

`<applicationSettings>
  <AppName.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="" serializeAs="">
      <value></value>
    </setting>
  </AppName.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>`
method, which is what I get when I use the application properties Settings tab.

Either way, the settings are recognized if I run the application as administrator, but not if I run it as a normal user.

Comment: I'm giving up on this post due to lack of responses. My work-around was to use a different file entirely for my settings.  I added a Settings.xml file to the project, marked it as a content file and made sure the setup project included content files.

Comment: I think the link I will share explains your case, and what is suggested; to use your own config file. Check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14085aa4-5301-488c-a623-89119c8ab54a/access-to-path-denied-issue-in-win-application-with-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Thanks @balayoglu. The article is helpful. That wasn't exactly my problem, but it WAS related. I couldn't edit the config file, got permission error. Solved it *wrong* way by giving full control to the app folder, but it works. Still doesn't address why standard user can't read config, but admin can. Either can read my settings.xml file. I will however move my settings to ProgramData. Thanks again...

Comment: Here is challenge: Don't want to use ProgramData folder directly, want to put settings in C:\ProgramData\CoName\MyApp\Settings.xml (or similar). In context of setup project, I can use [Manufacturer]\\[ProductName] to build folder. But how to get that path at run-time in actual application? Do I need to hard-code the Manufacturer part? Or maybe add that information to the app.config file? Thanks.